# mod_rewrite rule to remove .php extension now shows full file system path

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I'm in the process of migrating a site across from Wordpress to Octopress - but have managed to completely screw up the `mod_rewrite` settings in the process.

Currently, all the URLs are in the format

`http://site.com/archives/yyyy/mmm/posttitle.php`

Once ported across to Octopress, they are now in the format:

`http://site.com/archives/yyyy/mmm/posttitle`

There are also some top-level pages which are all variations of

`http://site.com/pagename.php`

and are now

`http://site.com/pagename`

I've got as far as

`RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php $1`

which seems to work nicely - but as soon as I include a 301 redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php $1 [R=301]
```

the rewrite rule now includes the full file system path - so:

`http://site.com/var/www/octopress/archives/yyyy/mmm/posttitle.php`

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong here?

*ETA*

The `RewriteRule` is in the `<Directory>` block:

```
<Directory />
 ReWriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php $1
 Options FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: Include *all* your rewrite rules and the context they are in (`.htaccess` file, vhost, global, `<Directory />` block, etc.), they can all matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex is matching on the filesystem path rather than the URL, which happens in Directory and htaccess context. in VirtualHost context it matches the URL, as detailed in the Apache HTTPD 2.2 documentation for RewriteRule:

> What is matched?
>
> In VirtualHost context, The Pattern will initially be matched against the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before the query string (e.g. "/app1/index.html").
>   In Directory and htaccess context, the Pattern will initially be matched against the > filesystem path, after removing the prefix that lead the server to the current RewriteRule (e.g. "app1/index.html" or "index.html" depending on where the directives are defined).
>   If you wish to match against the hostname, port, or query string, use a RewriteCond with the %{HTTP_HOST}, %{SERVER_PORT}, or %{QUERY_STRING} variables respectively.

[1](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

Comment: Moving the `ReWriteRule` out of the `<Directory/>` block and into the main `<VirtualHost>` block works a charm. Simple when you know how :-)